# How to JSON replace multiple nested array values in one single SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

I have table field called `values` which has a current JSON value of the following:

`{"roles": ["1","2","3","4"]}`

I also have another table called `roles` as below

| id | role_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin |
| 2 | Finance |
| 3 | Payroll |
| 4 | Accountant |

I am trying to use the `JSON_REPLACE` function to replace the id numbers in the `values` JSON string with the role names.

Basically it should have a result like this

`{"roles": ["Admin","Finance","Payroll","Account"]}`

But I cannot use `JSON_REPLACE` like `JSON_REPLACE('["1","2","3","4"]', '$[0]', Admin, '$[1]', Finance)` because the number of IDs and role names may vary differently, that's why I need to know how to do this in a single SELECT statement.

Comment: Did you mean to write: `{"roles": ["1","2","3","4"]}` ?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. Amended @bloodyKnuckles

Comment: Does this have to be pure MySQL?

Comment: Yes. strictly MySQL if possible, as other types may cause it to not work.

Comment: What "other types may cause it to not work" ? Are you saying you don't have have a server-side language like PHP available?

Comment: My apologies if I am misunderstanding something.. a bit new here. But I am restricted to use MySQL language to resolve this issue due to work/external policy reasons.

Comment: Parse JSON, join `roles` table, reconstruct JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_table`:

```
select json_object('role', (select json_arrayagg(r1.role_name) 
  from json_table(t.value, '$.roles[*]' columns(role int path '$')) r 
  join roles r1 on r.role = r1.id)) 
from vals t
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ff07664cf9dc143221413c28b740de92).

Comment: I tried the above solution. but it returned me a result of ```{"roles" : null}``` instead. Is there a way to replace the current roles JSON string values instead of needing to create an object?

Comment: @lyracarat03 Can you share your code in a fiddle?

Comment: Hi, sorry I had a slight typo in my code when i was testing. it is working now. Thanks!